# Перечисление в середине предложения

Tags: пунктуация, перечисление

у меня пунктуационный вопрос по этому предложению:

Как итог, право просто не могло игнорировать это явление и в отдельных юрисдикциях [?] США, Канада, Россия [?] стали появляться судебные прецеденты с попытками дать эмодзи правовое значение.

Не могу понять какие знаки должны стоять в данном предложении, где в середине идет перечисление. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Как итог, право просто не могло игнорировать это явление **,**(и поэтому) и в("отдельных" я убал, чтобы не мешать согласованию) юрисдикциях США, Канады и России стали появляться судебные прецеденты с попытками **при**дать(или присвоить - лучше, чем "дать") эмодзи правовое *значение*(тоже не уверен, что точное слово, возможно, "правовой статус" лучше).

Как итог, право просто не могло игнорировать это явление, и в отдельных юрисдикциях - США, Канада, Россия - стали появляться судебные прецеденты с попытками дать эмодзи правовое значение.

Как итог, право просто не могло игнорировать это явление, и в отдельных юрисдикциях(США, Канада, Россия) стали появляться судебные прецеденты с попытками дать эмодзи правовое значение.

Вроде так.